# WPF databinding to a property in the same control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

In this example the IsEnabled property of my button is bound to the selected rows "Local" property of the grid and it works just fine:

```
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="100" Height="100" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=dataGridRestore , Path=SelectedItem.Local}"></Button>

        <my:DataGrid x:Name="dataGridRestore" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                     >

            <my:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="restoreCntextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Open" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </my:DataGrid.ContextMenu>

            <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Local" Binding="{Binding Local}"  />
        </my:DataGrid>
```

Now when I move the button from outside my grid to inside the context menu of the grid my binding doesn't work. Why is this and how can i fix it?

```
        <my:DataGrid x:Name="dataGridRestore" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                     >

            <my:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="restoreCntextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Open" />
                    <Button  Width="100" Height="100" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=dataGridRestore , Path=SelectedItem.Local}"></Button>
                </ContextMenu>
            </my:DataGrid.ContextMenu>

            <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Local" Binding="{Binding Local}"  />
        </my:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Local}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

I tested it with ContextMenu of DataGridRows and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the RelativeSource attribute instead of the ElementName?

can't test it right now but something like this :

```
<Button  Width="100" Height="100" IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:DataGrid}},Path=SelectedItem.Local}"></Button>
```